# What is the recommend rest component for rest DSL

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse

I am using fuse6.3 on EAP and FIS2.0 on ocp, the rest DSL has the following Camel components integrated with it:

```
Servlet component (camel-servlet).
Spark-Rest component (camel-spark-rest).
Netty HTTP component (camel-netty-http).
Netty4 HTTP component (camel-netty4-http).
Jetty component (camel-jetty).
Restlet component (camel-restlet).
```

There is detail description for the above components for reference, but we want to know, from the best practice,  is there any high level guide on which could be the best choice?

Best regards

Lan

Comment: See this Admin Guide: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.3/html/apache_camel_development_guide/restservices-restdsl

Comment: Refer this guide: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.3/html-single/apache_camel_development_guide/#RestServices

Answer (score 1):

| I use | choice |
| --- | --- |
| JBOSS Fuse 6.x,7.x | camel-netty4-http |
| Apache Camel 3.x | camel-netty-http |
| servlets | camel-servlet |

| component | note |
| --- | --- |
| camel-servlet | goes well with spring-boot with embedded tomcat |
| camel-spark | producer only |
| camel-jetty | consumer only |
| camel-restlet | deprecated and has been removed in camel 3.x |
| camel-netty-http | producer and consumer |

Why did I choose netty? camel-netty-http is supported in future versions of Camel and it can be used as both producer and consumer.

- https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/spark-component.html
- https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/jetty-component.html
- https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/netty-http-component.html
- https://tomd.xyz/camel-rest/